# How do I automatically multiply columns by 100 to get percentage numbers in a pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, pgfplotstable

I have a csv file with percentages to load into a pgfplotstable. I already format them with siunitx but I did not find a possibility to shift the decimal point (multiply by 100) to get percentage numbers.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
\end{filecontents}

\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,
      display columns/0/.style={column type={S},string type},
      display columns/1/.style={column type={S},string type},
      display columns/2/.style={column type={S},string type}
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a preprocessing operation to the typeset definition:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
   col sep=comma,
   columns/0/.style={preproc/expr={100*##1}},
   columns/1/.style={preproc/expr={100*##1}},
   columns/2/.style={preproc/expr={100*##1}},
]{data.csv}
```

See the [PgfplotsTable manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf), section "Preprocessing Cell Content".

Answer (score 6):

Despite the accepted answer, I found another solution by using the built in style attribute `multiply with`:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
  col sep=comma,
  display columns/0/.style={column type={S},string type,multiply with=100},
  display columns/1/.style={column type={S},string type,multiply with=100},
  display columns/2/.style={column type={S},string type,multiply with=100}
]{data.csv}
```