# Switching between decimal, percentage points, and basis points in tables

Tags: tables, siunitx

How can I have LaTeX automatically move the decimal point in tables? For example, if I get numerical output from a program in levels (regular decimals), but would like to have it display in percentage points, is there a way to do this through LaTeX rather than going back and adjusting the numbers by hand?

I'm asking because I currently have a lot of tables already formatted with numbers in decimals. It would be super slick if I could find a solution to do this in LaTeX in batch rather than a) manually moving the decimal points in the table by hand or b) going back to the source, moving the decimal point there and then putting the results back into my LaTeX writeup.

Here is some example output with what I am thinking about.

[image: Example]

Here the same amount of significant figures are used, the only difference is the decimal point moves, which helps make the table more readable.

I've searched around and have not yet found a solution. I've skimmed the `siunitx` manual but do not think such a feature exists in that package. I did find a previous TeX Stack Exchange question titled, [How do I automatically multiply columns by 100 to get percentage numbers in a pgfplotstable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272510/how-do-i-automatically-multiply-columns-by-100-to-get-percentage-numbers-in-a-pg), which talks about this sort of issue but in a plot rather than a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst `siunitx` does not do 'multiplication' *per se* it does offer the possibility to use a fixed exponent. That combined with omitting the exponent in a table will achieve the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format = 1.3,
  table-omit-exponent, fixed-exponent = -2]@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & {Column 2} \\
\midrule
Something & 0.00143 \\
Or        & 0.00201 \\
Another   & 0.00174 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked exactly as described. I must have missed the fixed exponent part when skimming the manual. Thanks so much.